# Macbook Pro Sound doesn't work after Yosemite update

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

It has been more than a couple of months I have been looking for solution and I haven't found any yet. Here's my problem:

1. startup sound works
2. no 'internal speaker' in 'output device' in sound setting.
3. Audio midi setup has master volume set to 0. Cannot change the value.

This all happened after Yosemite update.

I have tried following so far

1. PRAM reset
2. sudo killall coreaudiod
3. plug in headphone and plug out (slowly, quickly and at every speed possible)
4. re-installing Yosemite

and other few I don't remember. 
I am now tired of looking for solution. I hope somebody here will be a god to me.

Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your second screenshot says "Digital Out".  Is there a light shining inside your headphone port?  In which case, the port is stuck in digital out mode (which I believe has no volume control).

Comment: @Ashley nope, there ain't any light shining inside headphone port. Select sound output device has only one option "digital out" while "internal speaker" used to be there too.

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you solve it?